# Performance issue with zClip and multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I added the zClip on my page which works pretty fine. 
My page currently has 100 buttons that put text on the clipboard (requirement).

Unfortunately this causes a performance issue when the page loads. 
At the moment i use a code like the one below.

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    $(this).zclip({
        path :  '/script/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy : function(text){
                return "Some Text";
            }
    });
});
```

With Zeroclipboard i had not performance issues with the exact same implementation. 
Is there any workaround or something that could fix this issue ?

Comment: Maybe binding and running the zlip right after the button is pressed instead of binding them all with a loop would be a workaround. Would that be possible ?

Comment: Instead of loading 100 zclips on the load page, i created a mouseover handler to load the zclip once the user goes over the button with the mouse. Unfortunately this does not work always when the user is manages to press before the zclip is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Changed it to load zclip into the element on mouseover of the element. Should probably add checks/flags to element so it doesn't get loaded onto the element multiple times.

```
$('.myClass').on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).zclip({
        path :  '/script/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy : function(text){
                return "Some Text";
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
    $(this).zclip({ 
        path: "/script/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy : function(text){
                return "Some Text";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a difference from what i wrote ?